# How can i write the regex "All characters are the same"?

Tags: java, regex

I would like it to match:

```
aaaaaa
bb
c
```

but not:

```
aaabaaa
cd
```

...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming the regex engine supports back-references,

```
^(.)\1*$
```

---

In Java it would be

```
theString.matches("(.)\\1*")
```

Comment: Trying java, but System.out.println("1111111".matches("^(.)\1*$")); prints false.

Comment: @Julio: Try `"^(.)\\1*$"`, with 2 backslashes.

Comment: @Kenny: In java `^` and `$` mean beginning and end of line, not string. Also regex matches are anchored by default. So just "(.)\\1*" will work.

Comment: @sepp2k: by default, `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the String, not line. When the `(?m)` flag is enabled, they match the beginning and end of a line. But when using `String.matches(...)`, `^` and `$` are not needed: by default, `matches(...)` will match the entire input string.

Comment: @Bart: The [javadocs for Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) say "^ The beginning of a line" and "$ The end of a line"

Comment: @sepp2k, well, then the JavaDoc is wrong. Try it yourself: `System.out.println("a\nb".matches("^a$\nb$"));` prints `false`, while `System.out.println("a\nb".matches("(?m)^a$\nb$"));` prints `true`.

Comment: @sepp2k, from the JavaDoc as well: *"By default, the regular expressions ^ and $ ignore line terminators and only match at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the entire input sequence."*

Comment: @Bart: You are right. And yeah, I just saw the other bit in the docs.

Comment: @sepp2k, it never occurred to me that `^` and `$` are described as you just mentioned: rather confusing from Sun, err, Oracle! :)

Comment: Adding the extra backslash made it work for me in Python 3.x Thanks

Comment: and what regex should be used for opposite purpose?

i need regex not to match values like "22222222" or "aaaaaaa"

Comment: @kennytm is there any opposite way to ignore, if all char or numbers are same?

Answer (score 8):

Using back references:

```
(.)(\1)*
```

Read: match any character followed by that same character 0 or more times.

Depending on the regexp engine and your needs, you might want to anchor the regex to only match the whole string, not substrings.

Comment: Trying Java, but System.out.println("1111111".matches("(.)(\1)*"));  prints false

Comment: @Julio: You need to double escape in java, i.e. use `\\1` instead of `\1`.

Comment: and what regex should be used for opposite purpose?

i need regex not to match values like "22222222" or "aaaaaaa"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture what you match, it is `^((.)\2*)$`

Answer (score 0):

Just for contributing to this question, you can use the BackRefence:

(\w+)\s+\1

It checks repeated words separated by whitespace.