# Javascript validation for number field specific masking and repetition number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have an `input` field which we need to mask and validate in this format:

```
xx-xxxxxxx
```

I have done masking using JS regex

```
<input type="text" id="taxvat" name="taxvat" value="" title="EIN/FEIN Number" class="input-text " data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="4">

document.getElementById('taxvat').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
          var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,7})/);
          e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '' + x[1] + '-' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
})
```

but can we validate this like no one can add value like this

```
11-1111111,22-2222222 etc
```

The input value can be different numbers but not all same like above. The accurate input is like different numbers

`12-2233232 or 26-3232356` etc

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you're got a regex you're already using, please add it to the question along with clear example of what ***should*** pass and what ***should not*** pass. From the description of the issue, I would assume you just need to add start/end string anchors.

Comment: Please share the regex you tried. Have you tried using the input `pattern` or `maxlength` attributes?

Comment: How do you expect your users to be stopped from entering all the same digits? Will the final digit get removed it is the same as the others?

Answer (score 0):

I had to look for help for a regular expression to detect if all characters in a string are the same. I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3258467/3397771

Leveraging this answer, I would re-write your listener to first remove the non-digit characters of the input text and then, if the result has the max count of characters, use the regular expression to test whether all the digits are the same one. If they are all the same, we will remove the last digit from the final, formatted text so that the user must enter a different digit.

```js
const MAX_NUM_DIGITS = 9;

document.getElementById('taxvat').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  let digits = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').slice(0, MAX_NUM_DIGITS);
  
  const isAllSameDigit = digits.length === MAX_NUM_DIGITS && /^(.)\1*$/.test(digits);
  
  if (isAllSameDigit) {
    digits = digits.slice(0, -1);
  }
  
  const formatted = `${digits.slice(0, 2)}${digits.length > 2 ? '-' : ''}${digits.slice(2)}`;
  
  e.target.value = formatted;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="taxvat" name="taxvat" value="" title="EIN/FEIN Number" class="input-text " data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="4">
```

The above works if there is a fixed number of digits that is expected to be entered by the user. However, if the number of digits that can be entered is not fixed, we need a different approach.

We will not be able to use an `input` event listener in this case because we don't know when the user has finished entering digits. Instead, we could add a listener to the `submit` event of the form and do the validation at that time:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#taxvat').on('input', function () {
    const digits = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    const formatted = `${digits.slice(0, 2)}${digits.length > 2 ? '-' : ''}${digits.slice(2)}`;
    
    $(this).val(formatted);
  });

  $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    const digits = $('#taxvat').val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    const isAllSameDigit = /^(.)\1*$/.test(digits);
  
    if (isAllSameDigit) {
      alert('Invalid! The digigts cannot all be the same');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="taxvat" name="taxvat" value="" title="EIN/FEIN Number" class="input-text " data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="4">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi its still allowing me to add same numbers like 11-111111,22-2222222

Comment: @OBAID It prevents the last character if it is the same as the rest. How else would you prevent all the same digit?

Comment: actually we want to prevent if all are same

Comment: @OBAID: The code I provided prevents 9 of the same digit being entered. If you need different logic, you need to specify what that logic is.

Comment: @OBAID: I have added an update with a form `submit` event handler.